# Возможна ли миграция записей с одного сервера БД на другой средствами mysql?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sql

Есть 2 идентичных сайта, отличаются только информацией в БД. Нужно перенести пользователей (и все связанные с ними записи) с одного сайта на другой (несколько тысяч пользователей) не прибегая к средствам php и пр. причем сделать это нужно корректно - т.е. после переноса автоинкременты все корректные, и т.д. и т.п. т.е. база после этого должна быть вполне работоспособной. Что при этом нужно учитывать? Возможно ли как-то автоматизировать процесс средствами mysql?

ЗЫ: структура таблиц 100% совпадает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой вариант - настроить репликацию и немножко подождать. Оно все синхронизирует. А потом просто в конфигах переключить на другой сервер.

почитать:

- [Основы репликации в MySQL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/56702/)
- [Настройка репликации master-slave в MySQL](http://handyhost.ru/books/mysql-replication.html)